# Sequelize: Cannot set a new unique constraint message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to setup a validation message for unique constraint violation for the fields `username` and `email`. However, whenever an already taken username is entered, it shows the message defined for the `email` property, but shows the input for the `username` property and also says that this input is for the `username` property. How would I fix this? Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var users = sequelize.define('users', {
        full_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                len: {
                    args: [5, 50],
                    msg: 'Your full name may be 5 to 50 characters only.'
                }
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: {
                msg: 'This email is already taken.'
            },
            validate: {
                isEmail: {
                    msg: 'Email address must be valid.'
                }
            }
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: {
                msg: 'This username is already taken.'
            },
            validate: {
                len: {
                    args: [5, 50],
                    msg: 'Your username may be 5 to 50 characters only.'
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                len: {
                    args: [5, 72],
                    msg: 'Your password may be 5 to 72 characters only.'
                }
            }
        },
        rank: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isInt: true
            }
        }
    }, {
        hooks: {
            beforeValidate: function (user, options) {
                if (typeof user.email === 'string') {
                    user.email = user.email.toLowerCase();
                }

                if (typeof user.username === 'string') {
                    user.username = user.username.toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return users;
};
```

This is the output I get from input:

```
{
  "name": "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError",
  "message": "Validation error",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "This email is already taken.",
      "type": "unique violation",
      "path": "username",
      "value": "hassan"
    }
  ],
  "fields": {
    "username": "hassan"
  }
}
```

So as you can see, it says it is the username that is not unique, but uses the message defined for the email property.

Comment: What if you define `unique` at indexes property , is the table structure created properly? http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#indexes

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I gave up on this ages ago.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix It is not possible according to an issue I opened in GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because it is a schema-validator, and not a general validator that falls inside the `validate: { }` object. The only work around is to include `defaultValue: ''` and then have a `notNull` object in the `validate` object. Otherwise, just removing `allowNull` disables most `validate: {}` checks.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible try like this

```
unique: {
    arg: true,
    msg: 'This username is already taken.'
},
```

Comment: Can confirm that this works

Comment: With typescript `arg` wasn't accepted and I had to add `name` field, to create the unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

```js
isUnique(value) {
          
          return User.findOne({where:{name:value}})
            .then((name) => {
              if (name) {
                throw new Error('Validation error: name already exist');
              }
            })
        }
```